# Powerbuilder .net, MVVM and unit testing

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, powerbuilder, powerbuilder.net

I'm complitely new to powerbuilder .NET
And I was working with WPF and used MVVM.

Is there any way to work with powerbuilder .net WPF and use MVVM design?
Can you tell me please the best practices and frameworks to work with it and with unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

This demos could help you   :
 http://gopowerbuilder.web12.hubspot.com/rich-resources/tutorials---demos/